# How to navigate Instance Method?

Tags: python, tree

I am using posStatParser

```
from stat_parser import Parser, display_tree
parser = Parser()

evaluate =  parser.parse("""    

In it's first elections, Aam Aadmi Party beats Sheila Dixit winning the Delhi Elections.  

""")
print (evaluate.treepositions)
```

Which returns:

```
<bound method Tree.treepositions of Tree(u'S+SBAR', [Tree(u'IN', ['in']), Tree(u'S', [Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'PRP', ['it'])]), Tree(u'VP', [Tree(u'VBZ', ["'s"]), Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'JJ', ['first']), Tree(u'NNS', ['elections'])])])]), Tree(u',', [',']), Tree(u'S', [Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'NNP', ['Aam']), Tree(u'NNP', ['Aadmi'])]), Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'NNP', ['Party']), Tree(u'NNP', ['beats'])]), Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'NNP', ['Sheila']), Tree(u'NNP', ['Dixit'])]), Tree(u'VP', [Tree(u'VBG', ['winning']), Tree(u'NP', [Tree(u'DT', ['the']), Tree(u'NNP', ['Delhi']), Tree(u'NNP', ['Elections'])])]), Tree(u'.', ['.'])])])>
```

How can i navigate through this instance method so i can manipulate individual parts.

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes no sense. You don't "navigate" methods.

You have never actually called the method. What you are seeing is simply the `__repr__` of the class. If you want the actual value returned by the method, you should call it:

```
values = evaluate.treepositions()
```

Comment: then how could i individually print parts of what was returned

Comment: Dunno, because I've no idea what it returns. A list, dict, class instance? You iterate through those like you would any other collection.

Comment: i just gave what returns

Comment: No, you didn't. I said you didn't, in my answer, which you replied to. **You have not called the method**. Once you do, you'll see what it returns.